# Regex find duplicate of partial string

Tags: notepad++, regex

Im stuck with regex command, to find duplicate of partial string.

1st problem:
This is what I have in my file

```
1;0197CE75;BC702
2;01966666;BC702
3;018B9AC5;BC702
42;018B9E21;BC702
6;018B9AC5;BC702
776;018BA0A4;BC702
```

As you can see I have 2x 018B9AC5, on 3; and 6;
I would like to use Notepad++ mark option, in CTRL+H, to quickly detect those 2 duplicates between ; ; in different rows. Is it possible?

2nd problem:
This is what I have in my file

```
1;0197CE75;BC702
2;01966666;BC702
3;018B9AC5;BC702
3;018B9E21;BC702
36;018B9AC9;BC702
776;018BA0A4;BC702
```

As you can see now I have 2x 3; can I mark that too somehow with another regex command or it is possible to have 1 regex command for both markings?

This regex:

```
(?=\b\w{8}\b)\w*[A-Za-z0-9]\w*
```

is marking all in 2nd column, i need only duplicates...

This regex:

```
^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
```

is marking the same rows, if there are duplicate rows

```
 3;018B9AC5;BC702
 3;018B9AC5;BC702
```

I need to mark duplicate of part of row... between ; ;

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do such job with Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is not the best tool for these kind of operations.

I don't thing you can mark duplicates, but I know of a way in which you may
extract them.

The article
[Sorting lines with plugin TextFX](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sorting_Text) says about using the TextFX plugin :

> To sort your text:
>
> - From menu: TextFX | TextFX Tools and select one of the following:
>
>   - clear the check mark for option "+Sort ascending" to sort descending order.
>   - enable the check mark for option "+Sort ascending" to sort ascending order.
> - Select the text, either lines of text or columns (see below for column mode select).
> - From menu: TextFX -> TextFX Tools -> {menu_cmd} where you select for {menu_cmd} one of the two commands at the top of the menu bar;
>     that is, either:
>
>   - "Sort lines case sensitive (at column)"
>   - "Sort lines case insensitive (at column)"
>
> TextFX Tools will sort only the lines you select. If you do a column
>   mode select (Hold Shift + Alt keys down and select text via mouse),
>   then it will sort all the lines that are at least partly selected, but
>   will sort them according to the selected part.

To be able to sort by column, you will need perhaps to replace the semi-columns
by a tab, at least temporarily.